# How does replication in team foundation server work

Tags: version-control, tfsbuild

We have two offices in different states and issues with performance when using integrated source control over the WAN. We were contemplating using replication in TFS to allow both office to have fast and robust connectivity. We need to understand network load, speed of access, how conflicts are managed.

Answer (score 2):

TFS has a proxy server which should help to aleviate the performance issues.

EDIT: Although i have never used it personally, the docs state that is exactly what it is for